# How to disable browser autocomplete on Input element in React.js

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome, autofill

I came across this issue a few days ago. Do you anyone knew how to disable browser autocomplete on the Input element in React.js??
I already tried :

- autoComplete="off"
- autocomplete="new-password"

Both are not working.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Read more on this large thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag). Disable autocomplete on the form level, if you have one. And make sure to use `autoComplete`, with uppercase C. But even then, you could have suprises.

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu I don't have inputs in the form because I'm submitting this via another component. So I need to disable autoComplete on input level.

Answer (score 2):

Solution from https://www.codementor.io/@leonardofaria/disabling-autofill-in-chrome-zec47xcui

> What solved the issue for me is setting the form fields to read only and then removing the attribute once the user focus them.

```
<input readonly="readonly" onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" type="text" value="test">
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I used solution mentioned here https://medium.com/paul-jaworski/turning-off-autocomplete-in-chrome-ee3ff8ef0908

Answer (score 1):

Yes, neither autoComplete="off" nor autocomplete="new-password" works with chrome.

Adding autocomplete attribute when input is focused works for me

`onFocus={(event) => { event.target.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off'); }}`

Answer (score 0):

On your input element delete the **type** attribute and all will be well. Also you don't need the autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

The tags autoComplete="off" and autocomplete="new-password" does not work with browsers. Add this to the input tags and it will work as expected.

```js
onFocus={(e) => e.target.setAttribute("autoComplete", "none")}
```